# MYSQL + Select & Delete at the Same Time

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select and delete at the same time?

eg: in one command or does this have to be run as 2 separate commands?

What is the most optimal way to read rows from a table (using WHERE) and then remove the rows that were read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You could run both commands in a transaction which will commit them as one atomic unit.